# Removing GOF in texreg with fixest library's feols regression object in R

Tags: r, broom, texreg, fixest

I am using feols from the fixest library in R and then texreg / htmlreg to create tables. I would like to exclude several Goodness of Fit measures from my table (AIC, BIC, loglikelihood, etc), but texreg interprets my regression as an object form the broom package:

```
1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  texreg used the broom package to extract the following GOF measures, but could not cast them to numeric type: within.r.squaredtexreg used the broom package to extract the following GOF measures, but could not cast them to numeric type: pseudo.r.squared
```

According to the documentation, "extract.broom" unfortunately does not have any arguments with which I can exclude GOF's. Any idea how I could proceed?

Answer (score 0):

`fixest` and `feols` should be supported natively by `texreg`. If they aren't, it would be helpful to provide a minimal self-contained example to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Landed here because same error occurs with `texreg::screenreg(lavaan::sem(model, data=PoliticalDemocracy))`. Using example from `?lavaan::sem`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/leifeld/texreg/blob/master/R/extract.R), there must be missing outputs in the model statistics, which in your case are within.r.squared and pseudo.r.squared. I would check the model outputs from feols before using texreg and see if any of them are missing.