# Error in exporting fixed effects feols model with texreg

Tags: r, texreg, fixest

I am trying to export fixed effects model estimated with `fixest` using `texreg`. It yields an error:

```
> library(fixest)
> library(texreg)
> 
> race <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=100)
> sex <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=100)
> stranger <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=100)
> dat <- data.frame(cbind(race, sex,stranger))
> 
> # Error happens when adding fixed effect
> model1 <- feols(stranger ~ race|sex, data=dat)
> texreg(model1)
Error in validityMethod(object) : 
  gof.names and gof must have the same length!
```

(reprex credit: Britte van Tiem)

GOF is goodness-of-fit. I lurked in the source code using `View(texreg:::extract)` and it seems the problem is with the calculation of R^2 and Adjusted R^2:

```
> texreg:::extract(model1)
Error in validityMethod(object) : 
  gof.names and gof must have the same length!
> texreg::extract(model1,include.rsquared = F, include.adjrs = F)


          coef.      s.e.         p
race 0.01061844 0.1296893 0.9479921

                 GOF dec. places
Num. obs.        100       FALSE
Num. groups: sex   2       FALS
```

I cannot understand how to get around it. Does anyone have a fix for this? A related problem is here but without the reprex. [Removing GOF in texreg with fixest library's feols regression object in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72164428/removing-gof-in-texreg-with-fixest-librarys-feols-regression-object-in-r)